# ScriptIntrinsicBlur generates inappropriate blur

Tags: android, bitmap, renderscript

I have been using ScriptIntrinsicBlur to blur one of my bitmap which actually filled with one SOLID COLOR. But the blur effect i get is really inapropriate. Kindly check the image below. The white portion is actually the bitmap i blurred. The bitmap actually fills the entire window with a solid color.

[image]

Below is may code for blurring.

```
static Bitmap blurBackground(Context context, int color, int width, int height){
    Log.d("AppLock","RENDER DONE in " + System.currentTimeMillis());

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200,200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(color);
    canvas.save();

    Bitmap blurredBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(context);

    Allocation inputAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript,blurredBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL
            ,                   Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);
    Allocation outputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(renderScript,inputAllocation.getType());

    ScriptIntrinsicBlur bluerScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript,Element.A_8(renderScript));
    bluerScript.setInput(inputAllocation);
    bluerScript.setRadius(15f);
    bluerScript.forEach(outputAllocation);
    outputAllocation.copyTo(blurredBitmap);
    bitmap.recycle();
    renderScript.destroy();
    Log.d("AppLock","RENDER DONE in " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    return blurredBitmap;

}
```

I have been following a tutorial from here [Link To Tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-renderscript-support-library-with-gradle-based-android-projects)

I have looked into numerous posts here and i am aware that i should use ARGB_8888 for render script. Also I tried changing the Element to Element.U8_4() . But what it does is just gives me back a Bitmap of 200x200 pixel and it actually fills the entire window. I don't know what am i doing wrong. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. If you blur solid color, you will get solid color. what the point? or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Saehun Sean Oh I really dont understand how blur works. I would like to acheive a similar effect from the picture in the link. http://imgur.com/5hxYziV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is both Dimming and Blurring the background, not just blurring a solid color.

Try following this tutorial: http://allegro.tech/2015/08/android-fogger.html

or Jump right into the library: https://github.com/allegro/fogger

Comment: Sorry for not putting the detailed code here. I've never used this library so I can't tell you how exactly this works. Glad this helped. 

If you have time, can you kindly post your code as an answer so even if link gets destroyed somehow, SO has the answer? Good practice to answer, but I'm working atm lol

Comment: Sure will post them once done. The library looks well and good. Thanks for the link